# Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some continuous function $f(x)$ defined in R.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

In the following question,

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions defined in R. Suppose that $|f_{n+1}(x)−
> f_n(x)| ≤ \frac {n^2}{1+2^n}$
>   for all x ∈ R and for all n ≥ 1. Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to some continuous
>   function $f(x)$ defined in R.

I was thinking of using induction, since I know that $|f_{n+1}(x)−
f_n(x)| ≤ \frac {n^2}{1+2^n}$, then from $f_n$ to $f_{n+1}$ it would be uniformly convergent and $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions, then there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $\varepsilon >0$, ${\displaystyle |x-x_{0}|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\varepsilon .}$ but I'm not too sure how to format it in order to make it clear

Comment: First show it's uniformly Cauchy then argue as in sequences Cauchy implies converges.  Uniformly Cauchy implies uniform convergence.   Proof should be analogous

Comment: thank you, that's a more straightforward way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$$ $$ = |f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)+f_{n-1}-f_{n-2} +\cdots f_{m+1}(x)-f_m(x)|$$ $$ \le |f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x|+|f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}| +\cdots |f_{m+1}(x)-f_m(x)|.$$

Comment: $|f_n(x)=f_m(x)|$ ? Do you mean $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$ ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, fixed.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: That's not really an answer but it's a hint on how to show it's uniformy Cauchy.

Comment: Yes, it helped a lot with my proof